# Apply local patch to new GIT version

Tags: git, patch, git-clone

There is a large program product, I've downloaded it's sources in ZIP file a few months ago. (ver. 3.7.28 at that time). I was working hard on few specific patches (about 70 files in different subfolders were created or modified). I've noticed their product at github, my modifications will not be accepted there, they simply don't need it. Actual version is 3.7.30 now (I've checked history, some of my files were modifed, but never in that peices). 
I'm not very familiar with git. I know, that I can create local copy:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/foo/proj-remote.git
```

I have a local modified files in folder *proj-modified* for version 3.7.28

How can I now prepare a patch-set (or some of taht kind) and merge it with their updated version in local copy? And do it everytime, when they produce new version and I download? (apply my old and new patches)

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what changes you have made and make a suitable patch.

Clone the github repository to your own account, and checkout the exact commit which corresponds to the sources you originally downloaded.  Create a new branch in git, where you will work from here on.  In the new branch apply the patch.  You should now have the same sources as you had at the beginning.

Commit the new sources.  Push back to your account.

Whenever you do work from hereon do it in the branch you created above.

When new commits are available in the original repository (not your clone) you can fetch from there and update your own branches with the changes.  You may want to study the documentation for this, as it may be a bit tricky if you are unfamiliar with it.

In the long run, I would suggest figuring out how to get your changes back into the main product to avoid having to maintain a fork.